# How to deploy Azure SQL S0 instance with ansible azure_rm_sqldatabase?

Tags: ansible, azure-sql-database

This or last week MS has changed Azure DB default deployment settings.
Our deployment script started creating General Purpose 2 vcores instances instead of S0 instances. I'm trying to fix it but looks like either documentation is not correct Or I'm doing someting wrong.

Our initial script was:

```
  azure_rm_sqldatabase:
    resource_group: "{{ resource_group }}"
    server_name: "{{ db_server }}"
    name: "{{ item }}"
    location: "{{ location }}"
  with_items:
    - "{{ database_list }}"
  register: async_result
  async: 7200
  poll: 0
```

According to the documentation it should be solvable by adding 2 parameters.

1. edition: standard
2. max_size_bytes: 268435456000‬

but turned out that it's not enough.

I've tried to use create_mode or decrease max_size_bytes but without luck.

```
- name: Create SQL Database for "{{ stack_name }}"
  azure_rm_sqldatabase:
    resource_group: "{{ resource_group }}"
    server_name: "{{ db_server }}"
    name: "{{ item }}"
    location: "{{ location }}"
    create_mode: default
    edition: standard
    max_size_bytes: 268435456000‬
```

In all the cases I'm getting the error:

```
failed: [127.0.0.1] (item={'_ansible_parsed': True, '_ansible_item_result': True, '_ansible_item_label': u'authentication', 
u'ansible_job_id': u'701489864709.12193', 'failed': False, u'started': 1, 'changed': True, 'item': u'authentication', u'finished': 0, 
u'results_file': u'/home/vb/.ansible_async/701489864709.12193', '_ansible_ignore_errors': None, '_ansible_no_log': False}) => 
{"ansible_job_id": "701489864709.12193", "attempts": 2, "changed": false, "finished": 1, 
"item": {"ansible_job_id": "701489864709.12193", "changed": true, "failed": false, "finished": 0, "item": "authentication", 
"results_file": "/home/vb/.ansible_async/701489864709.12193", "started": 1}, "msg": 
"Error creating the SQL Database instance: 400 Client Error: 
Bad Request for url: https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/1bbba5c5-fbdb-18d7-8128-b4d403d7c6c5/resourceGroups/test_rg/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/testserver/databases/authentication?api-version=2014-04-01"}
```

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong.

Update:
After upgrading ansible to latest version I've got another error:

```
DeserializationError: Unable to deserialize response data. Data: 268435456000‬, long, ValueError: invalid literal for long() with base 10: '268435456000\\xe2\\x80\\xac'"
```

I've decreased db size, database was created but, instead of S0 it was created as 2vcore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to create S0 instances by using the [azure_rm_resource](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/azure_rm_resource_module.html#azure-rm-resource-module) task. With this task you can do basically everything the azure api is offering.

Here the API operation to create [databases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/sql/databases/createorupdate).

Based on you initial script it should become:

```
azure_rm_resource:
  resource_group: "{{ resource_group }}"
  resource_name: "{{ db_server }}"
  provider: SQL
  resource_type: servers
  subresource:
    - type: databases
      name: "{{item}}"
  body:
    location: "{{ location }}"
    sku:
      tier: "Standard"
      name: "S0"
      capacity: 10
    properties:
      maxSizeBytes: 2147483648
with_items:
  - "{{ database_list }}"
register: async_result
async: 7200
poll: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to solve issue using azure_rm_sqldatabase so I had to workaround it with bash command. If I'll find better solution I'll update this answer.
In case if someone will face same issue here is the sample code:

```
- name: Create SQL Database for "{{ stack_name }}"
  command: bash -c "az sql db create --name {{ item }} --resource-group {{ resource_group }} --server {{ db_server }} --capacity 10 --edition Standard --service-objective S0"  
  with_items:
    - "{{ database_list }}"
  register: async_result
  async: 7200
  poll: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Like you, we have also experienced that. In my case: default creation of azure sql server database was using general purpose 4 compute (which is really expensive). From my experience, we were creating our db using t-sql code:

```
CREATE DATABASE 'dbName'
```

and that creates the expensive gen4 compute in azure. So I searched for some docs and according to documentation for [t-sql azure create database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-database-transact-sql?view=azuresqldb-current) it has arguments to create specific pricing tiers: `SERVICE_OBJECTIVE`, e.g., for S2 compute we now use the below t-sql:

```
CREATE DATABASE 'dbName' ( EDITION = 'standard', SERVICE_OBJECTIVE = 'S2' ) ;
```

This is now working for us. Although, I don't know how these parameters could be called from scripts or command lines, it should be possible to send `SERVICE_OBJECTIVE` as that might be the missing key.